# I want to start GWT "Entry module" compilation from command prompt

Tags: gwt, compilation, command-prompt

I want to create a batch file, Where i need to start the GWT compilation from the batch file (ie) from command prompt. Some one please help me in this

Comment: is it a maven project? if yes - go google maven gwt compiler plugin and it's goals

Answer (score 0):

The GWT compiler is a standard Java program. You need to add your app's dependencies **and** source folders to the classpath and then pass your module name as an argument. Details are in the documentation: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideJavaToJavaScriptCompiler

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advice you to create an ant file for this kind of task.

(others will prefer maven :))

Comment: The core purpose, I need to compile the project without eclipse. With a batch fie anybody can compile the code with a double click, that's what i need to know how

Comment: For ant or maven you also don't need eclipse.
The advantages of these are that they also work on MacOS and Linux. And imo an ant file is much easier to write and understand than a bat file.

If you want a bat just look at the webpage Thomas Broyer linked.
You just want to run the compiler, and zip the stuff the compiler outputs into a .war